# Add a filter that relevant to one kibana visualization only in dashboard?

Tags: kibana, dashboard, elk

I'm using ELK stack 7.4.0 OSS(Open source) version. ANd i have a already created dash board i want to Add a filter that relevant to one kibana visualization only in the dashboard. Then other visualizations should not get change by the filter. Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you not edit the visualization

Add filter

Enter whatever your filter is

Save the visualization.

Or does the filter need to change?

Comment: I want to get the filter from user like a search bar(input controller) for one visualization(area graph). The user will give the filter through search bar. But the other visualization in the dashboards should not get change due to the input by user. Any suggestions?

Comment: Ah then I dont think its possible, as far as Im aware, if the method needs to be changed by the user.

Answer (score 1):

I think that is not possible in Kibana Dashboard.

Filters on the dashboards are global filters for all the visualizations in the dashboard.

Comment: I want to get the filter from user like a search bar(input controller) for one visualization(area graph). The user will give the filter through search bar. But the other visualization in the dashboards should not get change due to the input by user. Any suggestions?

Comment: If you are developing a kibana visualization plugin then you can control that, but if you are using kibana native visualization then that is the feature for inbuilt visualization.

Comment: Any plugins that already developed? to do this kind of work or similar work

Comment: Here is the list of Known Plugins for Kibana - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/known-plugins.html. You can see if something matches your requirement, otherwise you have to develop.